# UIScrollView in iOS doesn't response scroll to top

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I have two UIScrollViews, one is horizental, the other is like page on the horizontal view. I want to click the status bar and have the vertical scrollView scroll to the top, but it doesn't work.

I searched for some information that said I must set `UIScrollView.scrollsToTop=NO`, but it doesn't work. Could somebody tell me why?

Comment: Create your won custom scrollview..

Comment: @iHungry that would be like rebuilding a house just because the door stopped opening, :]

Comment: yeah ur write, but i should have to write some descriptive comment on it.I want to write along with some code  @interface CustomScrollView : UIScrollView{
} .... this code is in .h file.... using this way u can create ur own custom UIScrollView. Set ur all properties in this class of initialization... also it gave a separate touch functionalities of respective scrollview

Answer (score 4):

The scroll view only scrolls to the top if there is a single scroll view present with the  scrollsToTop property set to YES.

Make sure it's set to NO on your horizontal scroll view and all the child, vertical scroll views contained within. Then, using the horizontal scroll view's delegate, as one vertical scroll view leaves the visible area, toggle the property to NO and toggle the incoming vertical scroll view's property to YES.